# Rolle theorem on infinite interval

Tags: calculus, continuity, rolles-theorem

We have :
$f(x)$ is continuous  on $[1,\infty]$ and differentiable on $(1,\infty)$

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x) = f(1)$

we have to **prove** that : there is $b\in(1,\infty)$ such that $f'(b) = 0$

I'm sure we have to use Rolle's theorem so, I tried using Mean Value theorem and using the limit definition  at $\infty$

Any ideas how can I use them ?

Update :

after seeking the answers that I've got :

I'm having trouble finding $\boldsymbol x_{\boldsymbol 1}\neq\boldsymbol x_{\boldsymbol 2}$ such that $\boldsymbol{f(x}_{\boldsymbol 1}\boldsymbol {)=f(x}_{\boldsymbol 2}\boldsymbol )$

*I need a formal solution

Comment: how much large intervals and can you explain more

Comment: Sorry. I had an idea that didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f\bigl(\frac 1x\bigr)$ for $x\in (0,1]$ and $g(0)=f(1)$. Then $g$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ and derivable in $(0,1)$. By Rolle's Theorem there exists $c\in (0,1)$ such that $g'(c)=0$, hence
$$0=g'(c)=-f'\Bigl(\frac 1c\Bigr)\frac 1{c^2}$$
thus if $b=\frac 1c$, then $f'(b)=0$ and $b\in (1,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 7):

Outline:

You may, and should, assume that $f$ is non-constant.

Pick $a$ so that $f(a)\ne f(1)$ (if no such $a$ exists $f$ is a constant function).

Choose a value $c$ that is in between $f(1)$ and $f(a)$.  Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show there is a $x_1\in(1,a)$ with $f(x_1)=c$.

Use the Intermediate Value Theorem and your limit condition to show there is  an $x_2\in(a,\infty)$ with $ f(x_2)=c$.

Now you're set to apply Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: I came to this Idea and I'm sure it should lead to the answer
but still I'm having trouble using the limit condition to show that there is x2 such that f(x2)=c
can you please show me ?

Comment: @WasFr Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=1$, you can find a $y>a$ such that $f(y)$ is in between $c$ and $f(1)$. Apply the IVT to $f$ on $[a,y]$ to find $x_2$.

Comment: Let's be more specific : What Epsilon shall I choose ? to make it done.

Comment: I solved it by choosing a minimal M for a given epsilon

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the existing answers:

Because of your hypotheses, the function defined by: $$g(t) = \begin{cases} f(\tan(t)) & t \in [\pi/4, \pi/2) \\ f(1) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) & t = \pi/2 \end{cases}$$ is continuous on $[\pi/4, \pi/2]$, differentiable on $(\pi/4, \pi/2)$, and $g(\pi/4) = f(1) = g(\pi/2)$. Apply Rolle's theorem to get $t \in [\pi/4, \pi/2]$ such that $g'(t) = 0$.

Compute $g'(t) = \tan'(t) f'(\tan(t)) = (1 + \tan(t)^2) f'(\tan(t)) = 0$. Therefore for $x = \tan(t) \in (1, \infty)$, $$f'(x) = 0$$

Comment: can you explain why : tan'(t)= $(1 + \tan(t)^2)$  ?

Comment: That's the derivative of the tangent function?

Comment: absolutely I missed that. yes nice answer thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is constant, the statement is trivial. If it is not, then we have some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\neq f(1)$.

- If $f(x_0) > f(1)$: Define the midpoint between $f(1)$ and $f(x_0)$ as $y=\frac{f(x_0)+f(1)}{2}$. Because the function has values $f(1)$ and $f(x_0)$ on the interval $[1,x_0]$, there exists such $a$ that $f(a) = y$. Because the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ is $f(1)$, there exists such an $M$ that $f(x) < y$ for all $x\geq M$. Because the function $f$ has values $f(x_0)$ and $f(M)<y$ on the interval $[x_0, M]$, there exists such a point $b$ that $f(b)=y$. Now use Rolle's theorem on $[a,b]$.
- If $f(x_0) < f(1)$: Define the function $g(x) = -f(x)$ and use the previous argument on $g$.

Comment: why we can deduct that there is an x such that f(x)>f(1)
maybe f(1) is an upper least bound ?

Comment: That's why I wrote without loss of generality. Either you have $x$ for which $f(x)>f(1)$ or you have $x$ for which $f(x)<f(1)$, in which case you can look at the function $g(x) = 2 - f(x)$ and use the same argument on $f$ as you did on $f$.

Comment: you mean you want to use Fermat's theorem for derivative on maximum or minimum ?

Comment: Yes. And the fact that the limit of $f$ is equal to $f(1)$ guarantees that either a maximum or a minimum exists.

Comment: but, the challenge is to show the solution in a formal way.
I agree with the idea that you are presenting but I'm in doubt of writing it formally. 
see the answer down I think it should lead to a formal solution
and read my comment maybe you can help me.
Thank you

Comment: It's entirely possible to formalize my proof. I will try to elaborate on some points to make this more clear.

Comment: Thank you I understood the process in general.

Answer (score 1):

Think about where $f(1)$ is. Pick a spot, any spot. Then think about all the points afterward. It's continuous and differentiable literally everywhere but possibly $f(1)$, and so we need to think about how it could *not* be flat somewhere.

First, we know it would be flat everywhere if $f(x)=f(1)$ a constant.

Next, we draw a line between $x = 1$ and $\infty$. At infinity, we have $f(\infty)=f(1)=K$ some finite constant. Then we think about how we draw a line from 1 to $\infty$ . If it's flat, ie $f(x)=f(1)=K$, then it is obviously true that $f'(x)=0$ everywhere between $1$ and $\infty$.

Now consider the case where it is non-constant.

Then we know there is a max (or min, by symmetry) $m$ such that $|f(m)|=|M|>k = f(1)$ on the number line. Now since $f$ is differentiable at $m \in (1,\infty)$, and $M$ is a max/min, it must be smooth and both sides smoothly approach it's flatness. This $m$ is your $b$ you are seeking to prove exists.

Comment: I agree with you . 
but I needed a more formal approach.